# PHP constant created from an array loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am going through a tute for PHP and have just come across this way of defining constants but without physically coding them in the file. I guess like all variables these dynamically created ones only exist when the code is run. I'm looking at some explanation as to how this works.

```
//or we can put them in an associated array
$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key),$value);
}

//method one of connecting to database
$connection = 
mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Constants are created with `define()` method. Later on you can use these constants where needed. But it's single time use, so it's overkill for such thing

Comment: yeah the more i look at it the more I think it is overboard. I still am grasping some of the conceptual ideas of php. but this one threw me a little in terms of where these variables existed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The constants are created and can be used any time after this code is run.

```
foreach($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key),$value);
}
```

You'll be able to access them as follows:

```
DB_HOST
DB_USER
DB_PASS
DB_NAME
```

The loop is definitely overkill and it's a bad way to write these constants out. They should just be defined follows:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USER', 'mydbuser');
...
```

I don't really get why the tutorial is asking you to loop over an associative array to access them as constants. I can only assume it's trying to show you how to define associative arrays and constants at the same time by taking a shortcut.

Comment: thanks for that. I think that is the case tbh. It is trying to shortcut the process of defining constants to populate a connection. But is doing it this way any more secure than just hardkeying the variables into the connection field?

Comment: No difference in security, you can go about it any method you wish. Ideally you'd store all your connection variables in a separate file and load them in. Like a config file, that could be a config.php file that you create and "require()" in your script. This way when you create future code that connects to the same database, you can just load the config file rather than hard coding all the details every time.

The reason it's not hardcoded, is to avoid duplication in the future.